# how to use the function ```num_to_schoice()```?

Tags: r, r-exams

I would like to built a simple probability exercise such that the solution is just a one decimal number between zero and one (different from zero and one). I would like to use the function `num_to_schoice`, but if I write:

```
num_to_schoice(0.3,digits=1,range=c(0.1,0.9))
```

I get the error message:

> NULL
>   Warning message:
>   In num_to_schoice(0.3, digits = 1, range = c(0.1, 0.9)) :
>     specified 'range' is too small for 'delta'

Could someone please explain how the function `num_to_schoice` should be properly used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me add a couple of points to existing answer by @Edward (+1):

If you generate a solution from the sequence 0.1, 0.2, ..., 0.9 and want four from the remaining eight numbers as distractors, I would recommend not using `num_to_schoice()`. Only if moving to a correct solution in 0.10, 0.11, 0.12, ..., 0.9, say, I would use `num_to_schoice()`.

#### Without `num_to_schoice()` for one digit

You can set up an answerlist with all nine numbers from the sequence, sorting the correct solution into the first position, and then using the `exshuffle` meta-information tag to do the actual sampling.

For example, in the data-generation you need something like this:

```
sol <- 0.3
ans <- c(sol, setdiff(1:9/10, sol))
ans <- paste0("$", ans, "$")
```

In the question you can then include

```
answerlist(ans, markup = "markdown")
## Answerlist
## ----------
## * $0.3$
## * $0.1$
## * $0.2$
## * $0.4$
## * $0.5$
## * $0.6$
## * $0.7$
## * $0.8$
## * $0.9$
```

Finally, the meta-information needs:

```
exsolution: 100000000
exshuffle: 5
```

This will then use the correct solution and four of the eight false answers - all in shuffled order. (Note that the above uses .Rmd syntax, for .Rnw this needs to be adapted accordingly.)

#### With `num_to_schoice()` for two digits

For the scenario with one digit using `num_to_schoice()` which tries to do too many things, but for more than one digit it might be useful. Specifically, `num_to_schoice()` assures that the *rank of the correct solution* is non-iformative, i.e., the correct solution could be the smallest, second-smallest, ..., largest number in the displayed sequence with equal probability. Specifically, this may be important if the distribution of the correct solution is not uniform across the possible range. This is the reason why the following code sometimes fails:

```
num_to_schoice(0.3, digits = 1, delta = 0.1, range = c(0.1, 0.9))
```

Internally, this first decides how many of the four wrong answers should be to the left of the correct solution 0.3. Clearly, there is room for at most two wrong answers to the left, which may result in a warning and a `NULL` result` if exceeded. Moving to two digits can resolve this, e.g.:

```
num_to_schoice(0.31, range = c(0.01, 0.99),
  digits = 2, delta = 0.03, method = "delta")
```

Remarks:

- Personally, I would only do this if the correct solution can *potentially* also have two digits. Otherwise students might pick up this pattern.
- You need to assure that to the left and to the right of the correct solution there is at least `4 * delta` so that there is enough room for the wrong answers.
- Using `delta = 0.01` would certainly be possible but if you want larger deltas then `delta = 0.03` or `delta = 0.07` are also often useful choices. This is because sampling from an equidistant grid with such a delta is typically not noticable for most students. In contrast, deltas like 0.05, 0.1, 0.02, etc. are typically picked up quickly.

Comment: Excellent answer! While you're here, may I ask why the `num2choice` function sometimes get caught in a never-ending while loop? Shouldn't it at least have a provisional escape clause to prevent the unwitting user from having to wait forever?

Comment: With the `delta` method, this can usually be avoided. With `runif` it might be possible, say, to put four random answers with `delta = 1` into an interval `c(0, 5)` but you might need to wait a really long time. That's why we recommend thorough testing for that. BTW: `stresstest_exercise()` is your friend here, see: <http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/stresstest/>

Answer (score 1):

Because your range is (0, 1), you have to specify a smaller `delta` than the default (1). The function calculates 5 wrong answers, so each has to be within the range you give AND far enough away from the other answers by an amount equal to `delta`. You should also use the "delta" method, since the package authors give the following advice:

> *Two methods can be used to generate the wrong solutions: Either simply
>   runif or otherwise a full equi-distant grid for the range with step
>   size delta is set up from which a discrete uniform sample is drawn.
>   The former is preferred if the range is large enough **while the latter
>   performs better if the range is small** (as compared to delta).*

So you can try the following:

```
num_to_schoice(0.3, digits=1, range=c(0.1, 0.9), delta=0.05, method="delta")
#$solutions
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

#$questions
#[1] "$0.6$" "$0.5$" "$0.3$" "$0.4$" "$0.8$"
```

Note that this function incorporates randomness, so you may need to try a few times before a valid solution appears. Just keep ignoring the errors.

---

**Edit**:
I did try this a few times and every now and then I got a warning about the specified range being too small, with a NULL result returned. Other times the function didn't do anything and I had to abort. The help page also has this tidbit:

> *Exercise templates using num_to_schoice should be thoroughly tested in
>   order to avoid problems with too small ranges or almost identical
>   correct and wrong answers! This can potentially cause problems,
>   infinite loops, etc.*

Inspection of the `num_to_schoice` function revealed that there is a `while` loop near the end which may get stuck in the aforementioned "infinite loop". To cut a long story short, it looks like you need to increase the digits to at least 2, otherwise there's a chance that this loop will never end. I hope it's ok to have 2 digits in the answers.

```
num_to_schoice(0.3, digits=2, range=c(0.1, 0.9), delta=0.01, method="delta")

$solutions
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

$questions
[1] "$0.23$" "$0.42$" "$0.22$" "$0.30$" "$0.54$"
```

I tried this 10,000 times and it always returned a non-null result.

```
res <- NULL
for(i in 1:10000){
  res[[i]] <- num_to_schoice(0.3, digits=2, range=c(0.1, 0.9), delta=0.01, method="delta")
}
sum(sapply(res, function(x) any(is.null(x))))
# [1] 0
```

Hope that works now.

Comment: So, I should not use ```method=delta```?

Comment: I tried creating a file "prova.Rnw" where I have written: ``` <<>>=

sc=num_to_schoice(0.3, digits=1, range=c(0.1, 0.9), delta=0.05)

@












%% \extype{schoice}
%% \exsolution{\Sexpr{mchoice2string(sc$solutions)}}
%% \exname{bayes}
%% \exshuffle{TRUE} ```` and then I tried to run ``` stresstest_exercise("prova") ``` but I always get the same error message. I also tride smaller delta, but I got the same. I would not like to have wrong answers outside the range (0,1) because they are probabilities.

Comment: Yes - you should use the delta method. The package authors mention in the help page: "[The delta method] performs better if the range is small (as compared to delta)". I've also updated my answer, which says you may need to have 2 digits. Let me know...

Comment: Thanks! That's certainly useful with a 2 digits solution. I would just change the range into `c(0.01,0.99)`. But still if I have a 1 digits solution, the risk would be that students could easily guess that the right answer is the only one where the second digit is zero. So, may question now is: if I just use the `sample()` function from scratch to create 4 wrong answers choosing from 0.1, 0.2, 0.4,..., 0.9  would it be ok? Or there is some reason I should avoid doing this and I should stick with the `num2schoice()` function?

Comment: First, I don't think students would guess that the answer with 0.30 has any more chance of being the correct answer than one with 2 digits, say 0.43. Maybe I'm wrong. But it's also possible with the sampling that you get 1 or 2 wrong answers with only 1 digit, say 0.50). I also tested this for different `delta` and found that assigning a value of 0.2 seemed to always work, meaning that a wrong answer is then more likely to have only 1 digit (but you still could get none). But a value of 0.5 seemed to hang every other run. Second, I think you can just use the `sample` function!

Comment: Oh, regarding your first point, you could always change the question so that the correct answer is 0.31 or some other probability that has 2 significant digits. :D

Comment: Good question and all good comments/answers, thanks (all +1). I've added a few more aspects in my response.